# get string value from Excel Package

Tags: c#

I need to get the string value from

```
List<UserLicense> B = new List<UserLicense>();
                B = applicationDbContext.ToList();
                foreach (var X in B)
                {
worksheet.Cells["H" + K].Value = X.Location; // output comes as (int)
```

Below is my location Class

```
public class SubLocation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string LocationName{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public static class Global
    {
        public static List<SubLocation> GetSubLocation()
        {
            List<SubLocation> subLocations = new List<SubLocation>();  
            subLocations.Add(new SubLocation { Id = 1, LocationName = "Brazil", Name = "Di Janero" });
            return subLocations;
        }

        public static SubLocation GetDetail(int id)
        {
            return GetSubLocation().Where(s => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

In userlicense model

```
  public List<SubLocation> Locations { get; private set; }
```

I tried to change it as below but the output is the same!

```
worksheet.Cells["H" + K].Value = X.Location.ToString();
```

Comment: What type is X? Not a SubLocation because this class has no _Location_ property

Comment: hi steve, can you check this property ? is it right ?

Comment: Sorry, but you are using a property from the _UserLicense_ class named _Location_ So far nothing references anything from the _SubLocation_ class. In the _UserLicense_ class what is the type of the property _Location_?

Comment: So… in the first code snippet… `B` is a `List` of `UserLicense` objects. Yet you do not show the structure of the `UserLicense` class… ? … In the third code snippet I assume this is the definition in the `UserLicense` class for the `Locations`… which is a list of `SubLocation` objects. Is what is ODD is that in the `UserLicense` class… the property is named `Locations` with an “s” however the first and last code snippets use “Location” without an “s” … ? … is there another property named `Location` in the `UserLicense` class … ? …

Comment: Assuming it is a typo in the first and last code snippets… then… since `Locations` is a `LIST`, then when you do something like… `worksheet.Cells["H" + K].Value = X.Locations;` … this will return an `int` value that is the number of items in the list. Adding `ToString()` will result in the same `int` value as a `string`. The code is trying to put “multiple” items into a single value and it doesn’t know how to do that. You need to either “flatten” the list or take a single item from the list.

Comment: yes JohnG > for your first comment; in userlicenses classic have public int Location { get; set; }

Comment: If the `UserLicense` class has an `int` `Location` property... Then what is the problem... ? ... in the first code snippet you have... `worksheet.Cells["H" + K].Value = X.Location; // output comes as (int)` ... why would you expect `X.Location` to be anything else?